# Comparing the GLMNET output of R with Python using LogisticRegression()

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, glmnet, lasso-regression

I am using Logistic Regression with the `L1` norm (LASSO).

I have opted to used the `glmnet` package in `R` and the `LogisticRegression()`from the `sklearn.linear_model` in `python`. From my understanding this should give the same results however they are not.

Note that I did not scale my data.

For `python` I have used the below link as a reference:

https://chrisalbon.com/machine_learning/logistic_regression/logistic_regression_with_l1_regularization/

and for `R` I have used the below link:

http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/36-classification-methods-essentials/149-penalized-logistic-regression-essentials-in-r-ridge-lasso-and-elastic-net/?fbclid=IwAR0ZTjoGqRgH5vNum9CloeGVaHdwlqDHwDdoGKJXwncOgIT98qUXGcnV70k

Here is the code used in `R`

```
###################################
#### LASSO LOGISTIC REGRESSION ####
##################################
x <- model.matrix(Y~., Train.Data.SubPop)[,-1]
y <- Train.Data.SubPop$Y
lambda_seq = c(0.0001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.0025)

cv_output <- cv.glmnet(x,y,alpha=1, family = "binomial", lambda = lambda_seq)

cv_output$lambda.min

lasso_best <- glmnet(x,y, alpha = 1, family = "binomial", lambda = cv_output$lambda.min)
```

Below is my Python code:

```
C = [0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.0025]

for c in C:
    clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', C=c, solver='liblinear')
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print('C:', c)
    print('Coefficient of each feature:', clf.coef_)
    print('Training accuracy:', clf.score(X_train_std, y_train))
    print('Test accuracy:', clf.score(X_test_std, y_test))
    print('')
```

When I exported the optimal value from the `cv.glment()` function in `R` it gave me that the optimal lambda is `0.0001` however, if I look at the analysis from `python` the best accuracy/precision and recall came from `0.05`.

I have tried to fit the model with the 0.05 in `R` and only 1 non-zero coefficient gave me but in `phython` I had 7.

can someone help me understand why this discrepancies and difference pleasE?

Also, if someone can guide me how to replicate `python` code in `R` it would be very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

At a glance I see several issues:

1. Typo: Looking at your code, in R, your first `lambda` is `0.0001`. In Python, your first `C` is `0.001`.
2. Different parameterization: Looking at the documentation, I think there's a clue in the names `lambda` in R and `C` in Python being different. In `glmnet`, higher lambda means more shrinkage. However,  in the sklearn docs `C` is described as as "the inverse of regularaization strength... smaller values specify stronger regularization".
3. Scaling: you say, *"Note that I did not scale my data."* This is incorrect. In R, you did. There is an `glmnet` argument `standardize` for scaling the data, and the default is `TRUE`. In Python, you didn't.
4. Use of cross-validation. In R, you use `cv.glmnet` to do k-fold cross-validation on your training set. In Python, you use `LogisticRegression`, not `LogisticRegressionCV`, so there is no cross-validation. Note that cross-validation relies on random sampling, so if you do use CV in both, you should expect the results to be close, but not exact matches.

There are possibly other issues too.

Comment: Thank you for this I will have a look at see if they work