# Is there a difference between Python Boruta and R Boruta?

Tags: python, r, feature-selection

I used the Boruta package in R and Python for the same dataset. And all the steps and other methods I applied are the same. But results of Boruta is different in Python and R for feature selection. In R, 46 feature are selected but 20 feature is selected in Python. What is the reason?

R

```
 M_boruta <- Boruta::Boruta(is_churn ~ . -cust_id, data = Mobile, doTrace = 2) 

print(M_boruta)

plot(M_boruta, xlab = "", xaxt = "n")

lz_2 <- lapply(1:ncol(M_boruta$ImpHistory),function(i)
  M_boruta$ImpHistory[is.finite(M_boruta$ImpHistory[,i]),i])

names(lz_2) <- colnames(M_boruta$ImpHistory)

Labels_2 <- sort(sapply(lz_2,median))
axis(side = 1,las=2,labels = names(Labels_2),
     at = 1:ncol(M_boruta$ImpHistory), cex.axis = 0.7)

M_boruta_attr <- getSelectedAttributes(M_boruta, withTentative = F)

M_boruta_df <- Mobile[ ,(names(Mobile) %in% M_boruta_attr)]

str(M_boruta_df)]
```

Python

```
  from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    from boruta import BorutaPy
    rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, n_jobs=-1,    class_weight='balanced',  max_depth=50)
    boruta_selector = BorutaPy(rfc, n_estimators='auto', verbose=2)
    churn_gsm_bor_x = churn_gsm_bor.iloc[:,1:].values
    churn_gsm_bor_y = churn_gsm_bor.iloc[:,0].values.ravel()
    boruta_selector.fit(churn_gsm_bor_x, churn_gsm_bor_y)
    print("=============BORUTA==============")
    print(boruta_selector.n_features_)
    print(boruta_selector.support_)
    print(boruta_selector.ranking_)
    churn_gsm_bor_x_filter=boruta_selector.transform(churn_gsm_bor_x)
    print(churn_gsm_bor_x_filter)
```

Comment: Have you gone through the parameter documentation to make sure that (a) they have the same definitions and (b) they have the same defaults? That has captured the differences in [past questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57855709/903061) that [I've answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55367955/903061).

Answer (score 0):

This might be because the parameters you specify for the Random Forest classifier in Python differ from the default parameters you use in R (cf. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf, or `ranger` in more recent versions of Boruta: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ranger/ranger.pdf).  I'd point out that you are also setting the maximum depth of the trees in the Python implementation higher than recommended (cf. https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/boruta_py) - personally I've found that this can have a large effect on how many features are selected.

Comment: The trees are bootstrap resampling in samples and dimensions, so there is a degree of random even run-to-run.  Extra-trees needs, impo, about 5x the sample-size that classic gini-split RF needs.  For many tasks more than about 100 trees doesn't change the labelling, and a convergence plot can show that.  https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Out-of-bag-error-for-the-training-of-random-forest-on-the-sample-trainsample-Figure_fig1_1917896

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/boruta_py/blob/92e4b4e1c3ee115a8e1997a8b4a25f8e5090236c/README.md?plain=1#L118), BorutaPy *should* behave exactly the same as Boruta R when `two_step=False` and `perc=100`. I found that while the algorithm is generally the same, the underlying default Random Forest parameters are not, which *could* be a cause of divergence. Even if we can hold all parameters between R and Python's underlying RF constant, there will be some stochastic process from RF that will lead to slightly different results. At least one [article](https://www.predictiveresearchsolutions.com/post/data-science-tips-feature-selection-using-boruta-in-python) tried to address this by bootstrapping Boruta. I also wanted to replicated behaviour between R and Python and found that the RF in R (using [ranger](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ranger/ranger.pdf)) diverged from [sklearn's RF](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) in these main ways (although there could be more) as [@eskrav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7065187/eskrav) has already pointed out.

**max.depth/max_depth:** The BorutaPy documentation suggests setting this to 5, but the defaults used in Boruta R are NULL corresponding to unlimited depth.

**num.trees/n_estimators:** This defaults to 100 in Python, but 500 in R.

**mtry/max_features:** “sqrt” means taking the square root of the number of features rounded down. R uses this method by default when no argument is given. Python uses 1 which is just all features.

**min.node.size/min_samples_split:** Default in Python is 2, default in R is 5.

From my investigation, this is the resulting closest RF setup:

```py
rf_closest_r = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=-1,
                            max_depth=None,
                            n_estimators=500,
                            max_features="sqrt",
                            min_samples_split = 5)

# Use HPs that should "behave exactly like R"
boruta_closest_r = BorutaPy(rf_closest_r, random_state=1, perc=100, two_step=False)
```

If you iterate this block changing the random_state, you might still see slightly different features selected depending on data complexity.